# If $bb_n \rightarrow b^2$ how do I show $bb_n>\frac{b^2}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

This is the only part I'm struggling to show in my proof of the quotient rule for sequences. I've tried setting $\epsilon$ to some values but I don't think what I am doing is correct.

Comment: This assumes that $b\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

If $bb_n \rightarrow b^2$ we have that $\forall \epsilon \quad \exists \bar n$ such that

$$\forall n\ge \bar n \quad |bb_n-b^2|<\epsilon \iff b^2 -\epsilon < bb_n < b^2 + \epsilon$$

then choos a suitable $\epsilon$.

Comment: ah i've got it: set $\epsilon =\frac{b^2}{2}$

Comment: @m.bazza Yes nice guess! Of course any positive $\epsilon \le \frac{b^2}{2}$ is fine!